# How to pass dynamic parameters to Dagger 2 at runtime

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger-2

I just started learning DI with dagger2. Not sure how to pass user credentials to Retrofit ServiceGenerator.

Here is how i provide the retrofit dependency in my module

```
 @Provides
 @Singleton
 APIService provideAPIService() {
 return ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class,"", "");
 }
```

The createService method takes in three parameters, The Service, username, and password. I'm passing in an empty string currently because there is no need for authentication currently. This is used for creating of an account.

This is how i obtain the dependency in my repository:

```
 @Inject
    APIService mAPIService;
    @Inject
    SharedPrefsHelper mSharedPrefsHelper;
    @Inject
    AppDatabase mAppDatabase;
    @Inject
    Context mContext;

    @Inject
    public SignupRepositoryImpl(AppDatabase appDatabase, APIService 
        apiService,SharedPrefsHelper sharedPrefsHelper, Context context){
        this.mAppDatabase = appDatabase;
        this.mAPIService = apiService;
        this.mSharedPrefsHelper = sharedPrefsHelper;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
```

Now, suppose a user has a login credentials, how do I modify the ServiceGenerator dependency in my module to include user-provided username and password?

I thought of modifying the module to include two arguments like this:

```
 @Provides
 @Singleton
 APIService provideAPIService(String username, String Password) {
 return ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, username, password);

 }
```

But I don't know where to go from here, how do i pass in the parameters at runtime? Also, a user might mistakenly input wrong credentials, I need to know how to nullify the ServiceGenerator and pass in a different credential.

PS: I'm not sure if i have provided enough information, please ask for anything.

Comment: My vote goes for that username/password would probably end up in the OkHttp interceptor.